# sonarqube: The x86_64 architecture is required for this software

Tags: sonarqube, homebrew

I'm trying to `brew install sonarqube` on a Apple M1 but I'm getting this error

```
sonarqube: The x86_64 architecture is required for this software.
```

is there a workaround ?

Comment: facing same issue even after downloading - `macosx-universal-64 % ./sonar.sh start` “wrapper” cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified.

Answer (score 4):

There are two workarounds.

Install LTS version instead with `brew install sonarqube-lts`, it seems to support M1 architecture with no issues.

OR

Install sonar through x86_64 brew:

1. Install x86_64 brew under /usr/local/bin/brew

```
arch -x86_64 /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

2. Create an alias for the x86_64 brew

Add to .zshrc:

```
# brew hack for x86
alias ibrew='arch -x86_64 /usr/local/bin/brew'
```

3. Install sonar

```
ibrew install sonar
```